# Cypress 5.0 full page screenshot auto mode

Tags: cypress

I am using Cypress5.0. I have configured the screenshots folder in cypress.json.
And I am running tests using cypress runner API programmatically.

I am using viewport values as :
config.viewportWidth = 1080;
config.viewportHeight = 1024;

The screenshot is coming, but it is not on the full page. My web page has scrolling, the screenshot is taking only visible area.

Please guide how to take full-page screen.

My Cypress.json

```
{
    "projectId": "yvs41u",
    "video": false,
    "integrationFolder": "integration-tests/experiences",
    "testFiles": "**/*.js",
    "fixturesFolder": false,
    "pluginsFile": "plugins/index.js",
    "supportFile": "support/index.js",
    "screenshotsFolder": "build/reports",
    "videosFolder": "build/reports",
    "videoUploadOnPasses": false,
    "trashAssetsBeforeRuns": false,
    "reporter": "mochawesome",
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "reporterOptions": {
        "charts": true,
        "html": false,
        "json": true,
        "reportDir": "cypress/reports/mochawesome",
        "reportTitle": "Archie Integration Testing Suite",
        "reportFilename": "report",
        "overwrite": false,
        "inline": true,
        "inlineAssets": true,
        "timestamp": "dd-mmm-yyyy-HH-MM-ss"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress by default captures only a viewport. In order to screenshot the whole page you need to configure the screenshot first:

```
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({ capture: 'fullPage' });
cy.screenshot();
```

As a result whole page will be captured.

Further read: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/screenshot-api.html

Comment: Thanks Jonah. I want to know how to configure this globally, so that I no need to  add cy.screenshot() in each and every tests file.

Comment: @pmrushi have you read https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/screenshot-api.html#Where-to-put-screenshot-configuration? Once you put the configuration in index.js it will be applied to all screenshots made during tests.

Comment: I have added below config in support/index.js file. But still not working fullpage screenshot, it is taking only view port screenshot.

Comment: Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
    capture: 'fullPage'
});
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
    if (test.state === 'failed') {
        let screenshotFileName = `${runnable.parent.title} -- ${test.title} (failed).png`;
        let imageUrl = `${Cypress.spec.name}/${screenshotFileName}`;
        let videUrl = `${Cypress.spec.name}.mp4`;
        addContext({test}, imageUrl);
        addContext({test}, videUrl);
    }
});